# Nested comprehension - inner loop inside an if loop

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

How do I exclude multiple parameters while inside a list comprehension?

I have a simple expression:
    data = [x for x in blob if e not in x.thing]

However instead of one string 'e' I would like to test multiple strings 
So a bit of pseudocode:

```
exclude = ['tom', 'dick', 'harry', ....]
data = [x for x in blob if <any of the values of exclude> not in x.thing]
```

I don't know the length or values of exclude so I can't do

```
[x for x in blob if e1 not in x.thing else x for x in blob if e2 not in x.thing else ... ]
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense. Edit your question and add what you are trying to achieve without comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, just copy paste this line:

```
[x for x in blob if all(e not in x.thing for e in exclude)]
```

for example :

Input :

```
exclude = ['tom', 'dick', 'harry']
blob=['franceharry','germany','gerrytom']
[x for x in blob if all(e not in x for e in exclude)]
```

Output :

```
['germany']
```